# Photoshop Script to Rename Layers to be Unique

Tags: javascript

I recently tried to dip back into my old JavaScript 'skills' to make a script for Photoshop. It's simply a recursive function that will loop over all the layers in a file and renames any duplicate names to add numbers so every layer name is unique.

In Photoshop, an `ArtLayer` is just a regular layer, and a `LayerSet` is a folder that contains layers, so I need to address them both separately. I wasn't sure if I could just make a function to do the main body of `renameLayerNames` because I wasn't sure if I could pass the `ArtLayer` and `LayerSet` objects by reference or if they'd become copies.

The format is copied from a pre-existing Photoshop script, so it might be funny looking and I'm not averse to changing it to fit how JavaScript normally works. I'm looking for all feedback, particularly about any notes about not writing 'proper' JavaScript style.

```
// Written by Gary Chadwick

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Dispatch
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

main();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Functions
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function: main
// Usage: the core routine for this script
// Input: <none>
// Return: <none>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function main()
{
    if (app.documents.length <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    layerNames = [];
    renameLayerNames(doc, layerNames);
    alert("Script complete.")
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function: uniqueName
// Usage: Conform name to be a unique name
// Input: Layer name and list of layer names
// Return: Unique name as a string
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function uniqueName(name, layerNames)
{
    dupe = 0;
    original = name;
    while (contains(layerNames, name)){
        dupe++;
        name = original + ' ' + dupe.toString();
    }
    layerNames.push(name);
    return name;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function: renameLayerNames
// Usage: Iterate over a list of layers to disambiguate duplicate names.
// Input: List of Layers and previously found layer names.
// Return: <none>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function renameLayerNames(layerSet, layerNames)
{
    var name = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < layerSet.artLayers.length; i++)
    {
        visible = layerSet.artLayers[i].visible;
        name = layerSet.artLayers[i].name;
        name = uniqueName(name, layerNames);
        layerSet.artLayers[i].name = name;
        if (!visible)
        {
            layerSet.artLayers[i].visible = false;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < layerSet.layerSets.length; i++)
    {
        visible = layerSet.layerSets[i].visible;
        name = layerSet.layerSets[i].name;
        name = uniqueName(name, layerNames);
        layerSet.layerSets[i].name = name;

        if (!visible)
        {
            layerSet.layerSets[i].visible = false;
        }
        // Recurse
        renameLayerNames(layerSet.layerSets[i], layerNames);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function: contains
// Usage: Check if an array contains an object.
// Input: An array, object to check for.
// Return: Boolean result of check
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function contains(array, object)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] == object){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```